# Visual Studio. Куда делась панель, где можно было смотреть ошибки комплилятора?

Tags: visual-studio

Случайно нажал что-то и исчезла. Такое было не первый раз, но уже не могу вспомнить что необходимо сделать, чтобы вернулась. Английская версия студии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изоffffffffбражения]

И иже с ним...................